# How to change values of a dataframe through groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, unique

Here I have a dataframe:

```
print te_c.head(10)

   Price          Vol   tradeDate
0     9            1  1994-05-09
1     3            2  1994-05-10
2     3            2  1994-05-10
3     3            2  1994-05-10
4     3            2  1994-05-10
5     4            3  1994-05-11
6     4            3  1994-05-11
7     4            3  1994-05-11
8     4            3  1994-05-11
9     5            4  1994-05-12
```

and a list:

```
te_index = range(1,te_c.drop_duplicates('tradeDate').shape[0] + 1)
```

Now I want to group `te_c` by `'tradeDate'`,and for each group let each`'Vol' * te_index[i]`(`i` from `range(len(te_index))`), then reset the `'Vol'` with this new data and make the desired output like this:

```
   Price          Vol   tradeDate
0     9            1   1994-05-09
1     3            4   1994-05-10
2     3            4   1994-05-10
3     3            4   1994-05-10
4     3            4   1994-05-10
5     4            9   1994-05-11
6     4            9   1994-05-11
7     4            9   1994-05-11
8     4            9   1994-05-11
9     5           16   1994-05-12
```

So I tried using for loop in the groupby function:

```
for name, group in te_c.groupby('tradeDate'):
  i = 0
  for j in range(group.shape[0]):
      group.ix[j, 'Vol'] = group.ix[j, 'Vol'] * te_index[i]
  i += 1
```

However my code didn't work and had:

> KEY ERROR:0L

I also tried to use `.apply()` but had no idea of how to multiply the groups by each `te_index`. How should I code to solve this problem?

EDIT: this calculation is only one of the calculations I wish to do through the dataframe, I also want to calculate something like `group.ix[j, 'Vol'] = group.ix[j, 'Vol'] * te_index[-(i+1)] / sum(te_index)` or `group.ix[j, 'Price'] = group.ix[j, 'Price'] * (te_index[i] * weights[i])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information on the `group index` stored in the `grouper` attribute of a `groupby` object:

```
te_c['new_vol'] = te_c.Vol.mul(te_c.groupby('tradeDate').grouper.group_info[0] + 1)

   Price  Vol   tradeDate  new_vol
0      9    1  1994-05-09        1
1      3    2  1994-05-10        4
2      3    2  1994-05-10        4
3      3    2  1994-05-10        4
4      3    2  1994-05-10        4
5      4    3  1994-05-11        9
6      4    3  1994-05-11        9
7      4    3  1994-05-11        9
8      4    3  1994-05-11        9
9      5    4  1994-05-12       16
```

You can also add the `group_info[0]` as a new `column` to facilitate the other calculations like so:

```
df['group_info'] = df.groupby('tradeDate').grouper.group_info[0] + 1

   Price  Vol   tradeDate  group_info
0      9    1  1994-05-09           1
1      3    2  1994-05-10           2
2      3    2  1994-05-10           2
3      3    2  1994-05-10           2
4      3    2  1994-05-10           2
5      4    3  1994-05-11           3
6      4    3  1994-05-11           3
7      4    3  1994-05-11           3
8      4    3  1994-05-11           3
9      5    4  1994-05-12           4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems that the `group_info[0]` doesn't connect to the value of `'Vol' column`? The value of `group_info[0]` remain the same when I change the value of `Vol`, still I can't use the new `column` to do the calculation. Or how should I use this `group_info[0]`?